How to store functions in Postman Collection Variables
I have some duplicate code I want to refactor and store in a postman collection variable.  This function code is only duplicated once in my postman unit tests but I don't want even one duplication.  So, I'm trying to store it in a collection variable and execute it however many times I need it.
As an arrow-function it works perfectly.
const parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime = milliseconds => {
    // From the milliseconds parm, this function calculates 
    // hours (h), minutes (m) and seconds (s) and returns a string like:  "0h 29m 59s".
    return parseInt(h) + 'h ' + parseInt(m) + 'm ' + parseInt(s) + 's';
};

Now I want to store this function in a postman collection variable.
Object.prototype.parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime = function(milliseconds) {
    // same code as above
    // From milliseconds parm, this calculates 
    // hours (h), minutes (m) and seconds (s) and returns this string.
    return parseInt(h) + 'h ' + parseInt(m) + 'm ' + parseInt(s) + 's';
};

This usage works perfectly.
let obj = {};
const timeToExpire = obj.parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(pm.collectionVariables.get('access_token_expiry')-new Date());
console.log('access_token valid for: ' + timeToExpire);

But, on unit tests somehow Postman references the function name in this error:
Response schema validation successful | Error: schema is invalid: data.properties['metadata'].properties['parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime'] should be object,boolean.

The response object does have a schema with data and metadata properties. That's ok.  How this error is occurring is perplexing.
This is the failing test.
    pm.test("Response schema validation successful", () => {
       const responseData = pm.response.json();

       const successSchema = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get("successSchema"));
       pm.expect(require("ajv")().validate(successSchema, responseData)).to.be.true;
    });

This is the successSchema layout.
Heading
const successSchema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        metadata: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                status: { type: "string" }
            },
            required: ["status"]
        },
        data: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                brandName: { type: "string" },
                goodsSupplierNumber: { type: "string" },
                supplierNumber: { type: "string" }
            },
            required: ["brandName", "goodsSupplierNumber", "supplierNumber"]
        },
        errors: {
            type: "array",
            items: {
                type: "object",
                properties: {
                    code: { type: "string" },
                    message: { type: "string" }
                },
                required: ["code", "message"]
            }
        }
    },
    required: ["metadata", "data", "errors"]
};
pm.collectionVariables.set("successSchema", JSON.stringify(successSchema));

Final note:  All my unit tests (322) worked until I tried to use a stored function in the collection variable.

What did your test look like before you let Postbot fix it?  The error is being caused by this line.  successSchema.properties['metadata'].properties['parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime'] = { type: ['object', 'boolean'] };  where you are literally adding a property called parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime to your schema which needs to be of type boolean, which is then failing in your test.  Not sure how this relates to your function at all.

Thanks... I updated the post and added "This is the test that's failing."  I removed the Postbot "fix".  I left that in for this post but the PostBot fix made no sense to me either.

I was misinterpreting the problem.  After looking at the issue again, it is not about the function stored as a collection variable.  That works.   It's why it's referenced/mentioned in a schema check--and causing an error..

I also have two other schemas I run the same validation for.  A "Fault" schema, and an "Errors" schema.  I get the same test error.  I thought maybe there was something wrong with the "Success" schema.

console log both variables before your assertion.  Do they look correct?  Is anything being injected into the successSchema?  I'm not sure how that function works unless you have other code that you haven't posted.   Your function is not stored as a collection variable.  The only reference to a collection variable is reading the access_token_expiry variable.  On a side note, the best way to store re-usable functions is as a global variable within a pre-request script.  I can show you an example of that if you want.  Object.prototype is not related to collection variables.

You could also clone the request and then remove all of the code related to the function,  leaving just the schema test in.  Do you get the same issue?  (I can't see that you are using that function anywhere).  You could also use the standard jsonSchema assertion instead of ajv.  pm.expect(response).to.have.jsonSchema(schema);

I would love an example.  I'm exploring new techniques here for me.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

One of the better ways to setup a re-usable function is to use a global variable in a pre-request script.
For example (the function itself is not important, its just an example).  You can put this at the request, folder or collection level.
utils = {
    parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime: function (milliseconds) {
        var seconds = Math.floor((milliseconds / 1000) % 60),
            minutes = Math.floor((milliseconds / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
            hours = Math.floor((milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
};

This is preferred to using EVAL which is not recommended, or by updating the prototype chain.
You can then call the method using.
var currentTime = +new Date(); // in milliseconds

console.log(currentTime);

console.log(utils.parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(currentTime));

With the resulting console logs.

If you want to use Postman functions, then you need to pass the pm method like following.
utils = {
    statusCode: function (pm, code) {
        pm.test(`Status code is ${code}`, () => {
            pm.response.to.have.status(code);
        })
        return utils;
    },
    response: function (pm) {
        console.log(pm.response.json());
        return utils;
    }
};

Which you can then call using..
utils.response(pm);
utils.statusCode(pm, 200);


I am so grateful.
